# How to save bulk lists of entites to database fast in spring-data-jpa?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, sqlite, spring-data-jpa

I have prepared list of new entities in `List<BinValue> binValues` variable.

Then I am trying to save it.

I noticed, that if saving them with

```
for(BinValue binValue : binValues) {
    binValueRepo.save(binValue);
}
```

then it works very slow.

And if save with

```
binValueRepo.save(binValues);
```

it tries to use multiple connections, but if limit connections to 1, then also works very slow.

Is it possible to speed up saving with something like serializing into

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Field1, Field2) VALUES ('Value1','Value2'), ('ValueA', 'ValueB')...
```

with many tuples and run in one batch?

**UPDATE**

I wrote this

```
@Override
   @Transactional
   public void saveBulkNewEntities(Iterable<BinValue> binValues) {

      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

      sb.append("INSERT INTO bin_values (bin_id, region_id, value) VALUES ");

      boolean juststarted = true;
      for(BinValue binValue : binValues) {

         if( !juststarted ) {
            sb.append(", ");
         }
         else {
            juststarted = false;
         }

         sb.append("(");
         sb.append(binValue.getBin().getId());
         sb.append(", ");
         sb.append(binValue.getRegion().getId());
         sb.append(", ");
         sb.append(String.format(Locale.US, "%f", binValue.getValue()));
         sb.append(")");



      }

      Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sb.toString());
      em.joinTransaction();
      query.executeUpdate();

   }
```

and got tremendous speed! Why!?

Comment: The most efficient way to bulk load data is to bypass the stateful session implementation (including spring-data) and use Hibernate's `StatelessSession` directly.

Comment: @Naros how to reach it from above Spring-Data-Jpa?